# How was S.H.I.E.L.D. funded in the dark days?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

After S.H.I.E.L.D. has been compromised by Hydra, it went dark without any government support.

How was the agency funded then to pay their highly trained staff, contractors, bills, airplanes (e.g. helicarrier) and high-tech tools? This sounds like some unlimited funding.

To quote the new director of S.H.I.E.L.D., Jeffrey Mace to Phil Coulson in S04E02 (14min):

> But what I don't have is the anonymous, unlimited funding you seemed to have before. To build billion-dollar airplanes?

What source was he referring to?

Comment: Exactly, if we have to tell you, we'd have to kill you.

Comment: Cross Site dupe - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55335/who-is-funding-non-official-s-h-i-e-l-d

Comment: @Paulie_D That happens all the time across many sites in SE (e.g. Unix questions).

Comment: Probably selling their extensive stocks of *handwavium* would be enough to keep the lights on.

Comment: I don't think a potential terrorist organisation operating in the shadows would be allowed to have any stocks, bank accounts or sell anything on the legal market.

Comment: @kenorb Shell corporations.

Comment: A part of me wonders if maybe Fury had something setup?  Or maybe Stark is still funding them but just doesn't know that Coulson is alive.